# Mocking Email component in CakePHP Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: cakephp, model, mocking

I'm trying to mock an email component in a model, but after the first function, Cake gives me an error: Error: Call to a member function to() on a non-object

Here's my test class:

```
<?php
App::uses('User', 'Model');

class UserTest extends CakeTestCase {
.
.
// I'm not copying the setUp and tearDown methods here, but they are there.
.
.
    public function testEmailTest(){
        $CakeEmail  = $this->getMock('CakeEmail',array('to','subject'));
        $CakeEmail->expects($this->any())
                ->method('to')
                ->with($this->equalTo('ant@b.com'));
        $CakeEmail->expects($this->once())
                ->method('subject')
                ->with($this->equalTo('hi'));
        $this->User->CakeEmail = $CakeEmail;
        $result = $this->User->emailCat();
    }
}
```

Here's the User model:

```
public $CakeEmail = null;

public function emailCat() {
    if ( !$this->CakeEmail){
        $this->CakeEmail = new CakeEmail();
    }
    $this->CakeEmail->subject('hi')
            ->to('ant@b.com')
            ->emailFormat('both')
            ->config('default')
            ->send('hi');

}
```

Cake v2.3.1.

Perhaps there is a different way to set multiple methods on this mocked function, but this was based upon a solution that somebody put online.

(I know I shouldn't be sending email from here, but for this one registration function, I want to keep it here so that I can rollback transaction if the email does not get sent).

Comment: are you sure you have `return $this;` at the end of your `expects` function?

Comment: You should double check the error message. Is it complaining about the User model or the test itself?
This code brokes MVC.